# how do i get information from 1 class to another

Tags: python, class, user-interface, kivy, return

New to python - kivy - gui

im trying to get information from 1 class to  another, the classes is basically the different screens i have for my GUI. ive research the return function but its not helping at all because im a  noob.

main GUI running on .kv file this is a breakdown of my code.

```
PROJECT_PATH = ""

class TrainNew1(Screen):
    #takes user input,i click a button to submit, runs this function.
    def test(self):
        PROJECT_PATH = self.ids.ProjectName.text 
        #will print PROJECT_PATH fine within test /class function
class TrainNew2(Screen):

    print(PROJECT_PATH) # will not print
```

Im not sure how to get it to print in the new class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you Need is `global` variables. Did you know about scopes? In Short Global variable is a type of variable that can be accessed/Modified from anywhere in the code file. Here's an Example :

```
PROJECT_PATH = ""

class TrainNew1(Screen):
    global PROJECT_PATH # this is required to modify the original PROJECT_PATH
    #takes user input,i click a button to submit, runs this function.
    def test(self):
        PROJECT_PATH = self.ids.ProjectName.text 
        #will print PROJECT_PATH fine within test /class function
class TrainNew2(Screen):
    global PROJECT_PATH # this is used to access PROJECT_PATH 
    print(PROJECT_PATH) # Now, It can be used/modified even inside in this class
```

Comment: Hello Mr Khushal Jangid. Thank you SO MUCH for taking the time to answer my question. You have helped me big time! im an experienced(amature) coder but im still learning the syntax to python, i didnt realize you can do this. more reasons to love python! thanks sir.

Comment: It was my pleasure, Sir :)